# remove unused dictonnary and list symbol in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, object

I have been trying to reformat some json data from a python query. I want the slug of my data to become the key of a dictionary. I did it but I have a list and a dictionary in extra. How can I remove them? I would like to have this result:

```
{
    "corps-connecte" :{
        "id": 9666888,
        "title": "Corps connect\u00e9",
        "slug": "corps-connecte",
    }, 
    "portal-thanos" : {
        "id": 9666888,
        "title": "Portal thanos",
        "slug": "portal-thanos",
    },...
}
```

But actually i have this :

```
[
   {
      "corps-connecte" :{
          "id": 9666888,
          "title": "Corps connect\u00e9",
          "slug": "corps-connecte",
          }, 
    },
    {
          "portal-thanos" : {
               "id": 9666888,
               "title": "Portal thanos",
               "slug": "portal-thanos",
         }
    }...
]
```

Here is how I did to get the data above, maybe there is an easier way that I can reformat my query correctly?

```
def artist_artworks(self, artist_id):
    artist = self.artist(artist_id)
    artworks = []

    with ThreadPool(self.threads) as pool:
        for artwork in pool.imap(self.artwork, artist["projects"]):
            keyList = [artwork["slug"]]
            valueList = [artwork]
            artworks.append(dict(list(zip(keyList, valueList))))
            continue
            break
    return artworks
    
def save_artists_json(self, artist):
  
    result = self.save_artist(artist)
    json_formatted_str = json.dumps(result)
 
    return json_formatted_str
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the raw json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your mistake is to have `artworks` be a list and append to it, instead of having it as a dict and updating it with the new artworks:

```py
def artist_artworks(self, artist_id):
    artist = self.artist(artist_id)
    artworks = {}  # <- Initialize as dictionary

    with ThreadPool(self.threads) as pool:
        for artwork in pool.imap(self.artwork, artist["projects"]):
            keyList = [artwork["slug"]]
            valueList = [artwork]
            artworks.update(dict(list(zip(keyList, valueList))))  # <- update items
            continue
            break
    return artworks
    
def save_artists_json(self, artist):
  
    result = self.save_artist(artist)
    json_formatted_str = json.dumps(result)
 
    return json_formatted_str
```

Comment: Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

You could just do:

```py
from pprint import pprint

x = [
   {
      "corps-connecte" :{
          "id": 9666888,
          "title": "Corps connect\u00e9",
          "slug": "corps-connecte",
          }, 
    },
    {
          "portal-thanos" : {
               "id": 9666888,
               "title": "Portal thanos",
               "slug": "portal-thanos",
         }
    }
]

y = {k: v for d in x for k, v in d.items()}

pprint(y)
{'corps-connecte': {'id': 9666888,
                    'slug': 'corps-connecte',
                    'title': 'Corps connecté'},
 'portal-thanos': {'id': 9666888,
                   'slug': 'portal-thanos',
                   'title': 'Portal thanos'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

alternate one-liner solution (but likely more inefficient):

```py
{next(iter(e)): e[next(iter(e))] for e in L}
```

an optimized version using walrus `:=` operator in Python 3.8:

```py
{(k := next(iter(e))): e[k] for e in L}
```

also maybe more efficient version:

```py
dict(e.popitem() for e in L)
```

more optimized version of above, as suggested in comments:

```py
dict(map(dict.popitem, L))
```

---

Timing the different options (run on Mac OS Big Sur, venv with Python 3.9.0)

```py
from pprint import pprint
from timeit import timeit
from copy import deepcopy

x = [
   {
      "corps-connecte" :{
          "id": 9666888,
          "title": "Corps connect\u00e9",
          "slug": "corps-connecte",
          },
    },
    {
          "portal-thanos" : {
               "id": 9666888,
               "title": "Portal thanos",
               "slug": "portal-thanos",
         }
    }
]

# 0.947
print('Items:          ',
      timeit('L = [z.copy() for z in x]; {k: v for e in L for k, v in e.items()}',
             globals=globals()))
# 0.827
print('Next -> Iter:   ',
      timeit('L = [z.copy() for z in x]; {(k := next(iter(e))): e[k] for e in L}',
             globals=globals()))
# 0.912
print('PopItem:        ',
      timeit('L = [z.copy() for z in x]; dict(e.popitem() for e in L)',
             globals=globals()))
# 0.734
print('Map -> PopItem: ',
      timeit('L = [z.copy() for z in x]; dict(map(dict.popitem, L))',
             globals=globals()))
```

Comment: All this is really doing is getting a key from `e`, then doing a lookup. So it could be boiled down to `{k: e[k] for e in L for k in e}`. Then, to avoid the unnecessary lookup, you wind up using `e.items()`: `{k: v for e in L for k, v in e.items()}` which is much more readable and idiomatic

Comment: @C.Nivs Not sure about idiomatic, but I find it slightly *less* readable. I guess because it's more to read. It's also slower.

Comment: I added a hopefully more efficient version. I figured out we could just use `popitem` dict method instead of calling `next(iter(x))` twice, which might have been way more inefficient

Comment: @rv.kvetch Oooh, that's right. Then you can just use `dict(map(dict.popitem, L))`.

Comment: bro, you just blew my mind. That is a much better solution lol - adding that as the possible solutions tested.